# AS3 How to Send Multiple Messages in writeUTF?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, tcp

So with TCP in AS3, I'm trying to write strings over to the server and then to the clients, but it appears to only be able to read one at a time. This is not good because I'm sending messages based on keys being pressed, and the client has an action that needs to be taken place based on what key is pressed. Since multiple keys can be pressed at a time, obviously it does not work correctly.

Client example:

```
if (keys[p1_jump_key])
        {
            p1_up = "down";
            sock.writeUTF("p1_up_down");
            sock.flush();
        }
        else
        {
            p1_up = "up";
            sock.writeUTF("p1_up_up");
            sock.flush();
        }
        if (keys[p1_crouch_key])
        {
            p1_down = "down";
            sock.writeUTF("p1_down_down");
            sock.flush();
        }
        else
        {
            p1_down = "up";
            sock.writeUTF("p1_down_up");
            sock.flush();
        }
```

And then here is the server:

```
function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void{
var socket:Socket = event.target as Socket;
var message:String = socket.readUTF();
for each (var socket:Socket in clientSockets)
{
        socket.writeUTF(message);
        socket.flush();
}}
```

And finally, here is the recieving client (I have a method that allows the server to differentiate between the two):

```
if(msg=="p1_down_down"){
        p1_down="down";
    }
    if(msg=="p1_down_up"){
        p1_down="up";
    }
    if(msg=="p1_up_down"){
        p1_down="down";
    }
    if(msg=="p1_up_up"){
        p1_down="up";
    }
```

Now many of you already see the issue, as when the down key is up, it sends the message "p1_down_up". When the up key is up, it sends the message "p1_up_up". Both messages are sending at once when neither of them are being pressed. The receiving client is, I suppose, just getting one of the signals, or perhaps neither of them. How do I make MULTIPLE signals get wrote and read over the server? I tried using an array but you can't write those apparently. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I don't really get it. I think I don't understand when you are triggering the socket data to be sent -- all the time? Only when a key is pressed or released? You should be able to send multiple messages, you just can only receive them one at a time, but they should all come through.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is sending all the time. I have made updates to the code and have made it so it only sends the message over when the key is pressed and right when it's released, but when multiple keys' messages are being sent at once, the recieving client doesn't seem to know what to do with it self--it behaves as if none of the messages are coming through at all.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this like I did trying to figure out how to accomplish this, I have to say that the other solution supplied is highly inefficient, overly complicated and too hard to read. Instead of adding a null byte to the end of your message and pushing packets into arrays, you can simply have the server send the length of the entire message to determine whether the message is in multiple packets, and to make sure you read multiple writes in the correct order.

Here is a working client receive function. I send data as compressed Objects converted to ByteArrays. Objects can store any type of data which make them a good candidate for transferring complex information from server to client.

```
var messageBytes: ByteArray = new ByteArray;
var messageLength: int = 0;
var readBuffer = false;

    function receiveTCP(e: ProgressEvent): void {


while (e.target.bytesAvailable >= 4) {//Loop to see if there is data in the socket that is available to read.
    if (messageLength == 0) {
        messageLength = e.target.readUnsignedInt();//read the first 4 bytes of data to get the size of the message and store it as our message length.
        readBuffer = true;//set the readBuffer to true. While this is true, the function wont be reading any more data from the server until the current message is finished being read.
    }

    if (messageLength <= e.target.bytesAvailable) {//check to see if our message is finished being read.
        if (readBuffer == true) {//Make sure another message isn't being read. Without this check, another incoming message from the server will overwrite the current one from being executed.
            e.target.readBytes(messageBytes, 0, messageLength);//reads the byte array into our messageBytes ByteArray declared at the top.
            messageBytes.uncompress();//decompresses our message
            var message: Object = new Object();
            message = messageBytes.readObject();//Writes our ByteArray into an object again.
            receiveMessage(message);//send our message to another function for the data to be executed.
            messageLength = 0;//reset our messageLength for the next message.
            readBuffer = false;//reset our buffer so that the client can read the next message being received, or the next message in line.
        } else {
            receiveTCP(e);//if there is another message in wait and the previous one isn't finished reading, execute the same function with the same event data again. Eventually the buffer will open and the message will be read.
        }

    } else {
        break;//If the message is split up into multiple packets, this will reset the loop to continue reading the message until all the packets are accounted for.
    }
  }
}
```

This will prevent Clogging, allow you to receive multiple messages simultaneously and put together messages that were delivered in multiple packets.

Admittedly, this took a while to figure out. If you need the serverside code for sending the message, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP protocol consists of a *bi-directional stream of bytes*, and as such message boundaries are not preserved. Due to this, if you are sending messages too often, you can end up reading from the buffer two messages instead of one.

Thus, some of the messages you are sending might be being processed together, which fails the comparison test on the receiving end.

To fix this, you can append a delimiter at the end of each message. This way, you'll know where every message you sent begins and ends, allowing you to split and process them separately. This also means you don't need to flush after every write to the buffer.

For instance, you could use a null byte (`\0`) as delimiter.

```
if(keys[p1_jump_key])
{
    p1_up = "down";
    sock.writeUTF("p1_up_down\0");        
}
...
sock.flush();
```

And on the receiving end, we trim any trailing delimiters and then split the message into the smaller packets.

EDIT: Fixing the issue you described gives rise to another one: your messages might be being split over two buffer reads. I've edited my code to reflect a solution to this, by creating a temporary variable where partial messages are stored, to be prepended to the other part(s) of the message in the following reads.

```
// First we check to see if there are any 'parts' of a message that we've stored temporarily from the last read. If so, prepend them to the message string, which must be its continuation
if(temp != "")
{
    msg = temp + msg;
    temp = "";
}

// Now we begin processing our packet
var splitPackets:Array = msg.split("\0");
var packets:Array = new Array();

// Deal with incomplete message reads
if(splitPackets[splitPackets.length - 1] != "")
{
    // If the last item in our array isn't empty, it means out message stream ended in a partial message. Hence, we have to store this value temporarily, and append it on the next read of the stream
    temp = splitPackets[splitPackets.length - 1];
}

// If the last item in our array is empty, it means our message stream ends in a full message
for(var i = 0; i < splitPackets.length - 1; i++)
{
    packets[i] = splitPackets[i];
}

for(var i = 0; i < packets.length; i++)
{
    if(packets[i] == "p1_down_down")
    {
        // Process each packet individually here
        ...
        // If you have already processed the packet, move on to the next
        continue;
    }
    // Processing code for other packets
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting an error at var packets:Array = msg.trim("\0").split("\0"); 1061: Call to possibly undefined method trim through a reference with static type String.

Comment: My bad. I just realized I mixed up my C# and my AS3. There's a trim method available, but it's in the Flex libraries. I've changed my code to reflect another method that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix, it DOES work, HOWEVER the game seems to get "clogged up" up with messages and eventually just does not respond correctly... here's what part of the server looks like:           `if (packets[i] == "p1_down_down")
{
socket.writeUTF("p1_down_down");
socket.flush();
continue; }                                                                                                               if (packets[i] == "p1_down_up")
{
socket.writeUTF("p1_down_up");
socket.flush();
continue;
}` Does this look fine?

Comment: Don't forget to add a null byte at the end of every message, or else they won't get parsed correctly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, yes, I have that in there, so it's like "p1_down_down\0".

Comment: Do I need to ALSO add a null byte to the SERVER'S message when it's sending them to the clients?

Comment: The message received by the client must have a nullbyte at the end. If the server is broadcasting the packet exactly how the client transmitted it, then it should already include the nullbyte, so there is no need to append it again. However, if that is not the case, the server should append a nullbyte at the end of the message, or they would 'hog' up like you said.

Comment: Well, I've just tried that, here's an example from the server: `if (packets[i] == "p1_down_down")
  {
   socket.writeUTF("p1_down_down\0");
   socket.flush();
   continue;
  }` And here's the client: `if (msg=="p1_down_down\0")
  {
   p1_down = "down";
  }` I have the same clogging issue though. Is there something I did incorrectly? Again thank you.

Comment: No worries. Where's the clogging happening exactly? Server, client, or both? And by clogging, what do you mean? That packets get added to the temp array? Or that they are all added to the packets array?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I changed "writeUTF" to "writeUTFBytes" and it's working now. Thank you so much, but I'll continue to test this and see if I have anymore issues, lol... but either way, again, thanks a lot, this has been incredibly helpful.

Comment: No worries, comment if you need anything. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved :)

Comment: Alright, well, I already ran into some issues, lol first off it only lets me press one key at a time, but more importantly, there seems to be an odd packet loss issue. I came up with my own method of getting the messages across before, and though it works perfectly, occasionally one of the clients won't seem to get one of the messages... like one of the characters will be in a different position than another one. This is odd because the characters are not supposed to move (on either client) until the message has reached them... and yet, they go off course from each other. What's going on here?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the whole code. I'd suggest you debug the messages being sent and received either side. The TCP protocol does not allow packet loss, and packets always arrive in the order that they are sent, so it must be a problem in your code. If they clients move and aren't supposed to, then that is for sure not network related. To me it seems like you are using something called dead reckoning for position prediction, which isn't very good unless you have extremely low latencies. Either way, as I said, that's another problem and you should open another question for that.

Comment: Is there a way we could talk about this through Email or something? It's difficult to paste parts of the code with these little comments. If you don't want to that's also fine, you've been very helpful. But I've been working on this game for over a year and REALLY want to get this networking thing working correctly. I'll credit you for sure if you can help me out further. But either way thank you.

Comment: Sure, what's your email?

Comment: Twisted4000@yahoo.com. Thank you.